# Will university marks/qualifications obtained during the pandemic largely through online assessment hold reduced value as we progress back to normal?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, grades, grading, covid-19

Do you think when we reach a point where students/graduates can be separated into pre-covid, during covid, post-covid, that the world - for the purposes of postgraduate admissions, employment - will view marks/qualifications from during the pandemic with increased skepticism? Speaking personally, I have to admit that the online situation boosted my results above what they were before/likely would have been, but at the same time I do think my actual understanding of the material was also enhanced.

Comment: Too early to tell, really. We are far from a post-Covid world.